# How to detect MySQL slave writes?

Tags: mysql, replication, linux

In a MySQL master-slave replication architecture, how do you detect if there have been (erroneously, since this should never happen!) direct writes on the slave?

For now, I'm running this command on the slave:

```
tcpdump tcp port 3306 and not host my_master_IP -A | grep -i -e INSERT -e UPDATE -e DELETE
```

whose output, if any, means writes on the slave, which is bad.

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to enable binary logging on the Slave. Why ?

With binary logging enabled on the Slave, each `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` recorded in the binary logs comes with the [server_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id) where the SQL statement originated.

### What if [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) was enabled ?

If you have [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) enabled on the Slave, every `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` from the Master comes with the Master's [server_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id). If any writes were executed on the Slave directly, you will have to separate the commands.

**EXAMPLE**: suppose the Master's [server_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id) is 10 and Slave's [server_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id) is 20. Now, let's say you have these binary logs on the Slave:

```
+------------------+------------+
| Log_name         | File_size  |
+------------------+------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 | 1073741824 |
| mysql-bin.000002 |  987741325 |
+------------------+------------+
```

You can separate the Master's commands from the Slave's commands like this:

```
mysqlbinlog --server-id=10 mysql-bin.* > Master_Commands.sql
mysqlbinlog --server-id=20 mysql-bin.* > Slave_Commands.sql
```

Then, you examine `Slave_Commands.sql` to see what commands were run and when.

### What if [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) was disabled ?

This would be better because the binary logs on the Slave should never increase in size on a Slave unless someone or something ran `INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs` locally.

**EXAMPLE**: Let's say you ran `RESET MASTER; SHOW BINARY LOGS;` on the Slave. For MySQL 5.6, you should see this:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| Log_name         | File_size |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |       120 |
+------------------+-----------+
```

From this point forward, if the binary logs ever change in size, this quicky tells you that someone or something ran `INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs` locally. Next, you run

```
mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.* > Local_Commands.sql
```

Then, you examine `Local_Commands.sql` to see what commands were run and when.

Comment: why not set the slave read-only?

Comment: @akuzminsky Good point. Slave should be `read_only=1;`. However, someone with SUPER can still run DML on the Slave. It's either this answer or upgrade the Slave to MySQL 5.7 with super_read_only (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_super_read_only)

Comment: well, of course an app account must not have SUPER. And an evil DBA can run DML with `SET sql_log_bin = 0`